# I am trying to do equations in python, i get this, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

Im a beginner and we have to do a lab assignment, basically the instructions say we have to enter the month and day of someones birthday as a single number (I.E. june 28 would be 628) then we have to print the month and the day individually (mainly where my problem lies), then give them their birthdate in xx/xx/2014.

the only way i can think to get the day is to take the original number (628) then subtract the month (which is the original/100 and formated to have no decimals) but i cant figure out how to do so

```
month_and_day = int(input ("Enter birthday as single number: "))
month = month_and_day / 100
print("month: ", format (month, "2.0f"))

print("day: ", month_and_day - format (month * 100, "2.0f"))



print("birthdate is: ", format (month, "0.2f"),"/", format (day, "0.2f"),"/ 2014")
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
print("day: ", month_and_day - format (month * 100, "2.0f"))
```

`month_and_day` is of type `int` but `format (month * 100, "2.0f")` returns a string, and you can't subtract a `string` from an `int`

Comment: so would i have to change it to 'int(format (month * 100, "2.0f")'

Comment: @Rickjames59 yes. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you should do all the integer calculations with `int`s and only then use `format()` to format the output printing

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is converting a number such as `628` to month and day to give them their birthdate like `6/28/2014`.

I suggest that you can use `time.strptime` to convert do it, like this:

```
>>> s='628'
>>> t=time.strptime(s, '%m%d')
>>> t.tm_mon
6
>>> t.tm_mday
28
```

So your program can be:

```
import time
month_and_day = input ("Enter birthday as single number: ")
birthday=time.strptime(month_and_day, '%m%d')
month = birthday.tm_mon
day = birthday.tm_mday
print("birthdate is: ", format (month, "0.2f"),"/", format (day, "0.2f"),"/ 2014")
```

You don't have to construct everything by yourself, if there is a standard library for you purpose, use it.